# How to search Data from select tag rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

[image]I'm trying to develop a web app using rails, which has Course Category and location modules.*Course* is interrelated to *Category* and *Location* with 'has_many' relation.

In my Course form, I need to sort out the courses based on Category. Can anyone help me to sort this out?

course.html.erb:

```
 <%= select_tag(:category_id, options_for_select(Category.pluck(:name, :id)),  class: "form-control custom-select" )%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding this code:
course_controller.rb

```
def index
  @courses = @courses.where(category_id: params[:category_id]) if params[:category_id].present?
end
```

course index.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag courses_path, :method => 'get' do %>
   <%= select_tag(:category_id, options_for_select(Category.order(:name).pluck(:name, :id) ,:selected =>params[:option]), onchange: 'this.form.submit();', class: "form-control custom-select" , include_blank: true  )%>
 <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [options_from_collection_for_select](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select) method to avoid using `pluck`. And if I'm not mistaken, you want to sort categories by name. So:

```
<%= select_tag :category_id,
               options_from_collection_for_select(Category.order(:name), :id, :name),
               class: "form-control custom-select" %>
```

---

**UPDATE**

So it looks like you need to send AJAX request on dropdown change and re-fill table content. Please, check this articles:

- [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) or [AJAX Introduction](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp)
- [jQuery .change() event](https://api.jquery.com/change/) or [change event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change)

We don't know what are you using to generate the table (simple partial, [DataTable-plugin](https://datatables.net/) or something else) so we cannot suggest to you the best solution for your case. But, for example, you can get updated table content as an AJAX response and refill the table in HTML.

Comment: I tried your code it is not sorting. I want the courses to be sorted based on category name

Comment: @SushmaKv `select_tag :category_id` means that this will be a dropdown list of categories, so it should contain categories, not courses. This line of code doesn't contain any information about courses at all. I guess you are confused about what you need and what you want. But if you really need to sort courses by category name, you need
`Course.joins(:category).order('categories.name asc').distinct`

Comment: I trying to search courses based on categories. For ex:  In my course index page , I want to sort a course based on categories. Plz, refer the image attachment I have added. In that, if I click on *AK HENNA* I want the courses related to the ak henna to be displayed. Note: ak henna is a category

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to sort the list of Courses you get as your search result.

So, try this:

```
@courses = Course.joins(:categories, :locations).where("categories.id LIKE ? and locations.id LIKE ?", "%#{params[:category_id]}%", "%#{params[:location_id]}%").order("categories.name ASC")
```

Comment: Glad that you found a solution! Can you please share the approach you used or mark the answer that helped you?

Comment: I have added the solution.do check

Answer (score 0):

You can always do something like this.

```
   <input list="cites" class="form-control" name="cites">
   <datalist id="cites">
       <% cites.each do |city| %>
       <option value="<%= city.name %>">
       <% end  %>
   </datalist>
```